# How to set same font size for all row in a table that has different label size in Swift?

Tags: swift, autoresize

I have a table view that has label for every row. I want to automatically resize width of the cells but after resizing, I have to set all label's font size same (actually, the smallest font size from the rows). I use this code block in viewDidLoad

```
@IBOutlet var cellLabel: [UILabel]!
@IBOutlet var cellContent: UIView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    for lbl in cellLabel {

        lbl.font = lbl.font.fontWithSize(cellContent.frame.height)
        lbl.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true;

    }

}
```

The output of the screen comes with different label size for each row.

I want to set smallest row's label's font size for all labels in the rows.

How can I implement it?

Comment: It might work in some cases but as far as i can see the code wont respond well when the cell is dequeued

Comment: do you want to it programmatically or you wanna do it with the help of storyboard?

Comment: Doesn't matter.. I can try both programmatically or in storyboard